# How to populate php/html form with MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax-error, forms

I am trying to create a program in which a user can update any specific product. When a user click on `UPDATE` button, a form opens. I want to populate `HTML` form with `MySQL` data. I have written the following code but its giving me an error message. I am sharing just the `HTML` part of the code.I am using this FORM inside PHP echo. Kindly check it.

**HTML:**

```
<label>Product Name:</label>  
</td>
<td>
    <input type='text' name='product_name' value='<?php echo $fetch['product_id']; ?'/>*Required  
</td>
</tr>
```

**Error message:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
(T_NUM_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\update_single_product.php
```

***COMPLETE CODE***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php

include 'connect.php';  
$id=    $_GET['product_id'];

    $select_query=  "select * from products Left join product_description 
        ON products.product_id=$id and product_description.product_id=$id";

    if(!$select_query_run=   mysql_query($select_query))
    {
        echo mysql_error();

        }

    else
    {
            $fetch =     mysql_fetch_array ($select_query_run);     



                echo "  
                <form action='insert_product.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
                <table border=1>
                <tr>
                <td>

                <label>Product Name:</label> </td>  <td><input type='text' 
                name='product_name' value='<?php echo $fetch['product_id']; ?>'  />*Required</td></tr>

                <tr><td><label>Item No:</label></td> <td><input type='text' name='item_no' ></td></tr>


            <tr><td>    Image3:</td><td> <input type='file' name= 'image3' ></td></tr></table>  ";


/*------------------
Drop Down List Start
------------------  */      


            echo "<select name='category'>";

                $select_query=          'Select * from category';
                $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);

                $sub_category_query=    "Select * from sub_categories";
                $sub_query_run=         mysql_query($sub_category_query);



            while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
            {

                        echo "<option value='".$select_query_array['category_id']."' >".
                        htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"]).

                        "<option value='".$sub_query_run['sub_category_id']."'  >" .
                        htmlspecialchars($sub_query_run['sub_category_name']).   "</option>".

                "</option>";




            }
            echo "</br>";

         $selectTag= "</br><input type='submit' value='Update Product'  /></select></form>";

         echo "</div></div>";

         echo $selectTag;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
echo "  
            <form action='insert_product.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
            <table border=1>
            <tr>
            <td>

            <label>Product Name:</label> </td>  <td><input type='text' 
            name='product_name' value='<?php echo $fetch['product_id']; ?>'  />*Required</td></tr>

            <tr><td><label>Item No:</label></td> <td><input type='text' name='item_no' ></td></tr>


        <tr><td>    Image3:</td><td> <input type='file' name= 'image3' ></td></tr></table>  ";
```

**With:**

```
echo '<form action="insert_product.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border=1>
            <tr>
            <td>

            <label>Product Name:</label> </td>  <td><input type="text" 
            name="product_name" value="'.$fetch['product_id'].'"  />*Required</td></tr>

            <tr><td><label>Item No:</label></td> <td><input type="text" name="item_no" ></td></tr>


        <tr><td>    Image3:</td><td> <input type="file" name= "image3" ></td></tr></table>';
```

As you can not use `echo` inside `echo`. And another thing you don't need to write `<?php` tags inside echo because you've already started the php tag.

Comment: You fixed it, but it's not the quotes, the close PHP tag was wrong.

Comment: I am using it inside the echo. I have posted the complete code. Kindly check it now.

Comment: @JohnV. agree. I didn't see that !! Editing my answer !! :) Thanks !!

Comment: Thanks you so much for the detailed answer. Now its not giving me any error message, but its also not showing any data in the input fields.

Comment: @TahaKirmani Try adding `$select_query_run=   mysql_query($select_query)` before `$fetch =     mysql_fetch_array ($select_query_run);` line.

Comment: It is still not working. It looks like there is some problem in my QUERY, because when I am echoing out the values outside the form, its not showing anything in the output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33953/discussion-between-pankit-kapadia-and-taha-kirmani)

Answer (score 2):

```
$id=    $_GET['product_id'];
$select_query=  "select * from products Left join product_description 
    ON products.product_id=$id and product_description.product_id=$id";
```

Please notice that you probably building a sql injection here. Please read the follow link how to prevent them.
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
value="<?php echo $fetch['product_id']; ?>"
```

instead of

```
value='<?php echo $fetch['product_id']; ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Morning try :

```
    <td><label>Product Name:</label> </td>  
    <td><input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $fetch['product_id']; ?>" required="required" aria-required="true"  />*Required</td>
```

that works fine for me..

noticed you have changed the code.. but you could always close the php before the form and use plain html on the form code and just use this...
It results in slightly tidier source code (if that matters)